# How do I make a user-authenticated local network shared folder

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

On Ubuntu 22.04, it's simple enough to right click a folder, choose "Local Network Share" and select the required settings. Then on another Ubuntu computer on the same network I can see the share folder, but it doesn't let me authenticate to access it. I've tried both the username and password of the user on the second computer and a username and password of the user on the host computer, but neither worked.

If I configure the share folder to allow guest access then I can access it anonymously from the second computer, but not write to it (even though I have checked "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" and run `chmod -R 0777` on the folder from the host machine)

When I search for help I'm always directed to the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, but nothing about this shared folder is written into that file - so where is the share configuration for this folder actually written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then on another Ubuntu computer on the same network I can see the
> share folder, but it doesn't let me authenticate to access it. I've
> tried both the username and password of the user on the second
> computer and a username and password of the user on the host computer,
> but neither worked

What is not clear from your post is if you added the server user to the samba password database. If my server user name - and the one I'm using from the client machine - is morbius I need to add myself:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a morbius
```

> On Ubuntu 22.04, it's simple enough to right click a folder, choose
> "Local Network Share" and select the required settings. .... .... When
> I search for help I'm always directed to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file,
> but nothing about this shared folder is written into that file - so
> where is the share configuration for this folder actually written?

When you create a share from Nautilus you are creating a samba "usershare". You can list all your shares created this way with this command:

```
net usershare info --long
```

And the share definitions themselves are located at /var/lib/samba/usershares - one file per object shared.

As for having only read access to the share I would suggest running the "net usershare .." command and updating your original post with the output.